# Windows 10 make CreateProcess failed

Tags: windows, make

I am trying to install a package from here https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec, which requires me to clone and run make. But I got into this error:

```
PS E:\SAFETY\SSE\sent2vec> make
c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -O3 -funroll-loops -c src/args.cc
process_begin: CreateProcess((null), c++ -pthread -std=c++0x -O3 -fun
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\dsvm\tools\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin\make.exe: *** [args.o] Error 2
```

Could you please explain what's wrong and what I need to fix please?

Thank you.

Comment: You're missing a `c++` command, likely the compiler, so you'll need to install that first. This project likely wasn't intended to be built on a Windows command line either; consider using either WSL or native Linux. If you insist on native Windows, you'll need MinGW or similar. I'd suggest you familiarise yourself with building C++ programs.

Comment: Thank you! I changed to Linux and it worked.